# Type Error when trying to append to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, append, typeerror, knn

I am writing code to perform a k-NN search on matrices of test and training data. There are three matrices in question; the test data, the training data and matrix that is one column and contains the respective classes for each row vector of the training data. I have defined a function that when give the row of a distance matrix, pairs each distance with a class and returns the k smallest distances with their classes. Here is the function;

```
def closest(distanceRow, classes, k):
    labeled = []
    for x in range(distanceRow.shape[0]):
        # | each element in the row corresponds to the distance between one      training vector
        # | and one test vector. Each distance is paired with its respective  training
        # | vector class.
        labeled.append((classes[x][0], distanceRow[x]))
    # | The list of pairs is sorted based on distance.
    sortedLabels = labeled.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    k_values = []
    # | k values are then taken from the beginning of the sorted list,  giving us our k nearest
    # | neighbours and their distance.
    for x in range(k):
        k_values.append((sortedLabels[x]))
    return k_values
```

When I run the code I get a type error at the line

```
k_values.append((sortedLabels[x]))
```

I get TypeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute '**getitem**' and I am unsure as to why.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `labeled.sort()` sorts the list *in place* and returns `None`. So `sortedLables` is `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This should be an answer :)

Comment: @Nizil: I already answered this in a more general way in the *other* question. :-)

Comment: Yes of course!! I can't believe I didn't see that, thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.sort()` returns nothing (as shown [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)).

You have to call `your_list.sort()` first and then perform operations with `your_list`.